# Mathematician Game Reimplemented

Tags: beginner, c, quiz

I coded my first projects in Java but now I also wanted to try C. I've read something about pointers and the rest of my programming knowledge I've "imported" from Java. With this project I tried to take root in C, because I am generally new in programming and thats why I am interested in many languages.

This is the project I've reimplemented:
[Textual mathematician game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166114/textual-mathematician-game)

I want you to evaluate and criticise my code. Especially I am not satisfied with the attributes()-function, but I dont see a more elegant way to implement this function without using an integer list without a descriptive name for the specific attribute. Also it feels like i am writing sort of Javacode just in C syntax. Also the exercise()-function looks like it contains repititive code. Is there a better or a shorter way to implement this function?

I am interested in your thoughts!

I've used the MinGW-Compiler.
The Program was compiled with the command: "gcc main.c"

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "exercise.c"
#include "player.c"

void info()
{
    printf("programmed by Henry Weinert\n");
    printf("\"0\" will close a menu or leave the game with saving\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    struct Player player;
    init(&player);
    printf("[4] save\n");
    printf("[5] info\n\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("[1] show character\n");
        printf("[2] calculate\n");
        printf("[3] attributes\n");
        printf("input: ");
        int input;
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("\n");

        if(input == 1)
        {
            show(&player);
        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {
            printf("number of exercises: ");
            scanf("%d", &input);
            printf("\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) 
            {
                calculate(&player);
            }
        }
        else if(input == 3)
        {
            attributes(&player);
        }
        else if(input == 4)
        {
            save(&player);
        }
        else if(input == 5)
        {
            info();
        }
        else if(input == 0)
        {
            save(&player);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**player.c**

```
struct Player
{
    // most important values
    int level;
    int experience;
    int experience_needed;

    char ranks[10][30]; 
    int rank;
    int rank_points;
    int rank_points_needed;

    int gold;
    int attribute_points;

    // attributes
    int intelligence;
    int wisdom;
    int dexterity;
    int intelligence_price;
    int wisdom_price;
    int dexterity_price;
};

void init(struct Player* player)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("save.txt", "r");
    if(file)
    {
        char line[12];
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->level = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->experience = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->experience_needed = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->rank = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->rank_points = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->rank_points_needed = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->gold = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->attribute_points = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->intelligence = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->wisdom = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->dexterity = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->intelligence_price = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->wisdom_price = atoi(line);
        fgets(line, 12, file);
        player->dexterity_price = atoi(line);
    }
    else
    {
        player->level = 1;
        player->experience = 0;
        player->experience_needed = 10;
        player->rank = 1;
        player->rank_points = 0;
        player->rank_points_needed = 500;
        player->gold = 0;
        player->attribute_points = 0;
        player->intelligence = 1;
        player->wisdom = 1;
        player->dexterity = 1;
        player->intelligence_price = 10;
        player->wisdom_price = 10;
        player->dexterity_price = 10;

        file = fopen("save.txt", "w");
    }
    fclose(file);

    strcpy(player->ranks[0], "Pupil");
    strcpy(player->ranks[1], "Student");
    strcpy(player->ranks[2], "Bachelor");
    strcpy(player->ranks[3], "Master");
    strcpy(player->ranks[4], "Doctor");
    strcpy(player->ranks[5], "Professor");
    strcpy(player->ranks[6], "Researcher");
    strcpy(player->ranks[7], "Renowned Scientist");
    strcpy(player->ranks[8], "Nobel Prize Winner");
    strcpy(player->ranks[9], "Mathematician");
}

void save(struct Player* player)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("save.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->level);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->experience);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->experience_needed);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->rank);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->rank_points);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->rank_points_needed);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->gold);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->attribute_points);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->intelligence);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->wisdom);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->dexterity);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->intelligence_price);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->wisdom_price);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->dexterity_price);
    fclose(file);
}

void show(struct Player* player)
{
    printf("Level        %d\n", player->level);  
    printf("Rank         %s\n\n", player->ranks[player->rank - 1]);
    printf("Experience   %d / %d\n", player->experience, player->experience_needed);
    printf("Rank Points  %d / %d\n", player->rank_points, player->rank_points_needed);
    printf("Gold         %d\n", player->gold);
    printf("AP           %d\n\n", player->attribute_points);

    printf("Intelligence %d\n", player->intelligence);
    printf("Wisdom       %d\n", player->wisdom);
    printf("Dexterity    %d\n\n", player->dexterity);
}

void increase_level(struct Player* player)
{
    while(player->experience >= player->experience_needed)
    {
        player->experience -= player->experience_needed;
        player->level++;
        player->attribute_points += 1;
        player->experience_needed = 5 * player->level * player->level + 5 * player->level;
        printf("\n");
        printf("----------\n");
        printf("-LEVEL UP-\n");
        printf("----------\n");
    }
}

void increase_rank(struct Player * player)
{
    while(player->rank_points >= player->rank_points_needed && player->rank < 10)
    {
        player->rank_points -= player->rank_points_needed;
        player->rank++;
        player->rank_points_needed = 250 * player->rank * player->rank + 250 * player->rank;
        printf("\n");
        printf("---------\n");
        printf("-RANK UP-\n");
        printf("---------\n");
    }
}

void reward(struct Player* player, int multiplier)
{
    int experience_reward = (player->intelligence * (1 + 0.1 * player->rank)) * multiplier;
    int rank_points_reward = (player->wisdom * (1 + 0.1 * player->rank)) * multiplier;
    int gold_reward = (player->dexterity * (1 + 0.1 * player->rank)) * multiplier;

    player->experience += experience_reward;
    player->rank_points += rank_points_reward;
    player->gold += gold_reward;

    printf("Exp  + %d\n", experience_reward);
    printf("RP   + %d\n", rank_points_reward);
    printf("Gold + %d\n", gold_reward);

    increase_level(player);
    increase_rank(player);

}

void calculate(struct Player* player)
{
    int difficulty = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    int amount_of_reward = exercise(difficulty);
    if(amount_of_reward > 0)
    {
        reward(player, difficulty);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Wrong\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void attributes(struct Player *player)
{
    int input = 1;
    while(input != 0)
    {
        printf("Gold %d   Points %d\n", player->gold, player->attribute_points);
        printf("Intelligence   %d   Price %d\n", player->intelligence, player->intelligence_price);
        printf("Wisdom         %d   Price %d\n", player->wisdom, player->wisdom_price);
        printf("Dexterity      %d   Price %d\n", player->dexterity, player->dexterity_price);
        printf("input: ");

        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("\n");

        if(input == 1)
        {
            if(player->attribute_points > 0)
            {
                player->attribute_points--;
                player->intelligence++;
                player->intelligence_price = 5 * player->intelligence * player->intelligence + 5 * player->intelligence;
                printf("Intelligence improved!\n");
            }
            else if(player->gold >= player->intelligence_price)
            {
                player->gold -= player->intelligence_price;
                player->intelligence++;
                player->intelligence_price = 5 * player->intelligence * player->intelligence + 5 * player->intelligence;
                printf("Intelligence improved!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not enough Gold and no attribute points!\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {
            if(player->attribute_points > 0)
            {
                player->attribute_points--;
                player->wisdom++;
                player->wisdom_price = 5 * player->wisdom * player->wisdom + 5 * player->wisdom;
                printf("Wisdom improved!\n");
            }
            else if(player->gold >= player->wisdom_price)
            {
                player->gold -= player->wisdom_price;
                player->wisdom++;
                player->wisdom_price = 5 * player->wisdom * player->wisdom + 5 * player->wisdom;
                printf("Wisdom improved!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not enough Gold and no attribute points!\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(input == 3)
        {
            if(player->attribute_points > 0)
            {
                player->attribute_points--;
                player->dexterity++;
                player->dexterity_price = 5 * player->dexterity * player->dexterity + 5 * player->dexterity;
                printf("Dexterity improved!\n");
            }
            else if(player->gold >= player->dexterity_price)
            {
                player->gold -= player->dexterity_price;
                player->dexterity++;
                player->dexterity_price = 5 * player->dexterity * player->dexterity + 5 * player->dexterity;
                printf("Dexterity improved!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not enough Gold and no attribute points!\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**exercise.c**

```
int exercise(int difficulty)
{
    int number1, number2, result;

    if(difficulty == 1)
    {
        number1 = rand() % 21;
        number2 = rand() % 21;
        result = number1 + number2;
        printf("%d + %d = ", number1, number2);
    }
    else if(difficulty == 2)
    {
        number1 = rand() % 26;
        number2 = rand() % 21;
        result = number1 - number2;
        printf("%d - %d = ", number1, number2);
    }
    else if(difficulty == 3)
    {
        number1 = rand() % 16;
        number2 = rand() % 16;
        result = number1 * number2;
        printf("%d * %d = ", number1, number2);
    }
    else if(difficulty == 4)
    {
        number1 = rand() % 101; 
        number2 = (rand() % 20) + 1; // generating zero leads to crash
        result = number1 / number2;
        printf("%d / %d = ", number1, number2);
    }

    int guess;
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    printf("\n");

    if(guess == result)
    {
        return difficulty;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including .c files *can* be done, yet forming .h files with the global functions and variables and using separate .c compilations is more idiomatic.

```
#include "exercise.c"  // hmmmm
#include "player.c"
```

---

Small detail: Be more generous in buffer size to read an `int`.  There really is no need to tightly control buffer input  to 12: 10 characters + \n + \0.  Consider that from time to time, the file will have unusual data.  So either add more error checking and exit code on bad input and/or have a generous buffer.  I suggest 2x expected worst case.

Additional error checks also suggested

What is the widest this could *ever* print?
Is 12 sufficient?    Mouse over below for pedantic needs

> `fprintf(file, "%d\n", INT_MIN); --> "-2147483648\n" --> char[13] to read back`
> 64-bit int would need char[22]

```
fprintf(file, "%d\n", player->gold);
...
// fgets(line, 12, file);
// player->gold = atoi(line);
char number[24];
if (fgets(number, sizeof number, file) == NULL) Handle_Error();
if (sscanf(number, "%d", &player->gold) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

---

OTOH, I do like to qualify input right up front.  Suggest a helper function to read an `int` and check its range and handle various errors detections.  Something like [Read_float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34906275/2410359)

```
#define GOLD_MIN
#define GOLD_MAX
...
if (read_int(file, &player->gold, GOLD_MIN, GOLD_MAX)) return FAIL
```

---

The whole alternate initialization could instead use a single assignment.

```
    struct Player player_default = { .level = 1, .experience = 0, .experience_needed = 10, 
         /* ... */} ;
    *player = player_default;
    // player->level = 1;
    // player->experience = 0;
    // player->experience_needed = 10;
```

---

```
number2 = rand() % 21; result = number1 / number2; --> might cause divide by 0
```

---

I like to avoid FP math when only `int` math is needed.  Converting a `double` to an `int` results in truncation and not always the expect result once code uses values that are not converted exactly.  (0.1 rarely forms an exact `double`)

```
// int experience_reward = (player->intelligence * (1 + 0.1 * player->rank)) * multiplier;
int experience_reward = 
  (player->intelligence * (10 + player->rank)) * multiplier / 10;
```

---

Highest level is not correct ;-)

```
// strcpy(player->ranks[9], "Mathematician");
strcpy(player->ranks[9], "Programmer");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why do you write Error_Handle() with capital letters? I heard that you should only use small letters, except your are writing some sort of class or in c, a struct. Thank you for your work!

Comment: @HenryWeinert "only use small letters" is a _style_ issue - not a universal axiom.  Follow your group's coding standard.  I did it for emphasis as I would have a set of functions to handle errors all beginning with something like `Error_`